# How can I turn a value of an array into the key of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am parsing a text file that looks more or less like this:

```
123.animal=cat
123.name=fred
123.food=fish
345.animal=dog
petshop=zoonoria
```

This is how I am parsing it:

```
$file_path = $filename;
$linesArray = file($file_path);    
$properties = array();

foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {

    if (strlen($line) && $line[0] == '#') {
        $pdate = substr($line, 1);
        $date = rtrim($pdate);
        $formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('* M d H:i:s T Y',$date);
        }



    if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
        $prop=array();    
        $prop[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
        $lineContArray = explode("=", $line);
        $identArray = explode(".", $lineContArray[0]);

        $ident = $identArray[0];
        $type = $identArray[1];     

        $value = trim($lineContArray[1]);

        $found = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i<count($properties); $i++) {
            if ($properties['number'] == $ident) {
                $properties[$i][$type]= $value;
                $found=1;
                break;
                }
            }
        if ($found == 0) { 
            if (!empty($type)) { 
                $properties[] = array('number' => $ident, $type => $value); 
                } else { 
                $properties[] = array($ident => $value); } 
            }
        }
```

My result is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "123"
    ["animal"]=>
    string(3) "cat"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "123"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "fred"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "345"
    ["animal"]=>
    string(4) "dog"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
   ["petshop"]=>
   string(5) "zoonoria"
  }
}
```

But I need the array to be different, this is the result I like to achieve:

```
  array(3) {
      [123]=>
      array(3) {
        ["animal"]=>
        string(3) "cat"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "fred"
        ["food"]=>
        string(4) "fish"
      }

      [345]=>
      array(1) {
        ["animal"]=>
        string(3) "dog"
      }
      [petshop]=>
        string(8) "zoonoria"
      }
    }
```

So my main problem is, I do not know how to turn `number` into the key. I tried various things, but I failed. I am really happy for every hint.

---

I tried the solution of Svetlio:

```
$file_path = $filename;
$linesArray = file($file_path);    
$properties = array();


foreach ( $linesArray as $str) {
        $exp = explode ('=', $str);
        if(count($exp) == 2){
                $exp2 = explode('.', $exp[0]);
                if( count($exp2) == 2 ) {
                        $properties [$exp2[0]][$exp2[1]] = $exp[1];
                } else {   
                        $properties [$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
                }
        } else {

        }

}
```

My result:

```
array(3) {
  ["123"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(3) "cat
"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "fred
"
    ["food"]=>
    string(4) "fish
"
  }
  [345]=>
  array(1) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(3) "dog
"
  }
  ["petshop"]=>
  string(3) "zoonoria
"
}
```

Comment: To fix Svetlio's answer, change `$linesArray = file($file_path);` to `$linesArray = file($file_path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

Comment: @Mark Baker Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working solution but it doesn't cover the cases where stings don't contain = or have more than 1 of them..

```
$strings = array(
    '123.animal=cat',
    '123.name=fred',
    '123.food=fish',
    '345.animal=dog',
    'petshop=zoonoria'
);
$array = array();
foreach ( $strings as $str) {
        // I accept that there is 1 = at strings possible 
        $exp = explode ('=', $str);
        if(count($exp) == 2){
                $exp2 = explode('.', $exp[0]);
                if( count($exp2) == 2 ) {
                        $array[$exp2[0]][$exp2[1]] = $exp[1];
                } else {
                        // if there are multiple/null dots i set the string as key
                        $array[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
                }
        } else {
                // what to do if there are no or many  = = = in the string ?
        }

}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: This seems to work very fine, I posted the result of your solution in my question. I am just wondering, why the `=` is in the next line?

Comment: rtrim ($str, "\n"); (at the first line inside the foreach) should remove the new line symbol you have at each string..

Comment: I tried `rtrim ($str, "\n");` right behind `foreach ( $linesArray as $str) {` but the `"` is still in the next line. Sorry by mistake I wrote `=` instead of `"`

Comment: Mark Baker gave a solution for the issue

Answer (score 1):

After getting the result you can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to get the desired result

```
$result = array_reduce($initialArray, function ($result, $item) {
    $number = isset($item['number']) ? $item['number'] : end(array_keys($result));

    if (!isset($result[$number])) {
        $result[$number] = array();
    }
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'number') continue;
        $result[$number][$key] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}, array());
```

Comment: I saw that.. In the mean time I've updated my answer.. As I could understood, if there is no number key in the item then it will be added to the last item of the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {

if (strlen($line) && $line[0] == '#') {
    $pdate = substr($line, 1);
    $date = rtrim($pdate);
    $formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('* M d H:i:s T Y',$date);
    }



if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
    $prop=array();    
    $prop[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
    $lineContArray = explode("=", $line);
    $identArray = explode(".", $lineContArray[0]);

    $ident = $identArray[0];
    $type = $identArray[1];     

    $value = trim($lineContArray[1]);

    $found = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($properties); $i++) {
        if ($properties['number'] == $ident) {
            $properties[$i][$type]= $value;
            $found=1;
            break;
            }
        }
    if ($found) { 
        if ($type && $ident) { 
                $properties[$ident][$type] = $value; 
            } else if (!$type && $ident) { 
                $properties[$ident][] = $value;
            }else if ($type && !$ident){
                $properties[$type][] = $value;
            }

    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you. I will be sure to take note of your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = '123.animal=cat
    123.name=fred
    123.food=fish
    345.animal=dog
    petshop=zoonoria';


$ini = parse_ini_string($data);
$result = [];
foreach ($ini as $key => $value) {
    $splitKey = explode('.', $key);
    $iniPtr = &$result;
    foreach($splitKey as $subKey) {
        if (!isset($iniPtr[$subKey])) { $iniPtr[$subKey] = null; }
        $iniPtr = &$iniPtr[$subKey];
    }
    $iniPtr = $value;
}
unset($iniPtr);

var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZXPn2)

In your case, use `$ini = parse_ini_file($file_path);` to read your file data into `$ini`

Comment: Thank you, I tested your code (also on a new php page only your code, nothing else) but my result is a blanc page. This is strange, because you posted a working demo. So I am sure I did something wrong. Just wanted to post the issue

Comment: @Jarla - what version of PHP are you running? Because I used short-array syntax for `$result = [];` which requires PHP >= 5.4.0.... if you're running less than that (besides recommending upgrading to a supported version) you'd need to use `$result = array();`

Comment: Ah, ok, I am going to test it!

Comment: Now it is working very well, thank you so much! ( ans I am going to upgrade php soon)

Comment: One other issue I would like to share: With my code I could parse files with around 5000 entries. It took around one minute. With your code, smaller files are working, but when I parse a large file, then I get the result `array(0) {}`